# Print variable inside loop

Tags: shell-script, for, exit-status

### 1. Summary

I want to print variables from loop.

**If** I place `echo $i` after command from loop:

[**Travis CI build passed**](https://travis-ci.org/Kristinita/SashaTidyDebugging/builds/348708406#L575).

**elif** I place `echo $i` before command from loop:

[**I get exit code 1**](https://travis-ci.org/Kristinita/SashaTidyDebugging/builds/348852806#L878).

I don't find:

1. why is this happening,
2. how I can print variable before command.

---

### 2. What the script should do

I use [**HTMLTidy for validate my HTML**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7514433/5951529).

I want, that HTMLTidy validate all HTML in folder `output` and subfolders of this folder.

See [**simply configuration**](https://github.com/Kristinita/SashaTidyDebugging/tree/SashaEchoInLoop) of my project.

Working equivalent Windows batch script:

```batch
@echo off
FOR /R %%i IN (*.html) DO echo %%i & tidy -mq %%i
```

---

### 3. Steps to reproduce

I print in console:

```
cd output && bash ../tidy.sh
```

- `../tidy.sh` — path to my script, see [**simply configuration**](https://github.com/Kristinita/SashaTidyDebugging/tree/SashaEchoInLoop).

---

### 4. exit code 0

**If** `tidy.sh`:

```bash
shopt -s globstar
for i in **/*.html; do
    tidy -mq $i
    echo $i
done
```

[**Travis CI build passed**](https://travis-ci.org/Kristinita/SashaTidyDebugging/builds/348708406#L575):

```bash
$ cd output && bash ../tidy.sh
line 8 column 9 - Warning: trimming empty <span>
SashaInFolder.html
line 8 column 9 - Warning: trimming empty <div>
subfolder/SashaInSubFolder.html
The command "cd output && bash ../tidy.sh" exited with 0.
Done. Your build exited with 0.
```

---

### 5. exit code 1

**Elif**:

```bash
shopt -s globstar
for i in **/*.html; do
    echo $i
    tidy -mq $i
done
```

[**Travis CI build failed**](https://travis-ci.org/Kristinita/SashaTidyDebugging/builds/348852806#L871):

```bash
$ cd output && bash ../tidy.sh
SashaInFolder.html
line 8 column 9 - Warning: trimming empty <span>
subfolder/SashaInSubFolder.html
line 8 column 9 - Warning: trimming empty <div>
The command "cd output && bash ../tidy.sh" exited with 1.
Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

---

### 6. Not helped

1. I try [**printf instead of echo**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/237999) → I get same behavior.
2. I can't find answer to my question in Google.

Comment: It would appear tidy is the one exiting with 1. You could look into using `tidy -mq "$i" || echo "tidy failed with $? on $i"`, in place of your current `tidy` command. It might help to explicitly `exit 0` reaching the end of your script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exit status of a `for` loop compound command is that of the last command executed in it¹.

```
for cmd in true false; do
  "$cmd"
done
```

Returns *false* (a non-zero exit status) because `false` was the last command run.

`echo` will return true as long as it successfully manages to write what we're telling it to.

If you want to return *false*/*failure* if *any* of the `tidy` command fails, you'd need to either record the failure, or exit upon the first failure:

```
#! /bin/bash -
shopt -s globstar
ok=true
for i in ./**/*.html; do
  if tidy -mq "$i"; then
    printf '%s\n' "$i"
  else
    ok=false
  fi
done
"$ok"
```

or:

```
#! /bin/bash -
shopt -s globstar
for i in ./**/*.html; do
  tidy -mq "$i" || exit # if tidy fails
  printf '%s\n' "$i"
done
```

That one could still return *false*/*failure* if `printf` fails (for instance, when stdout is to a file on a filesystem that is full).

If you want to ignore any error and your script to return *true*/*success* in any case, just add a `true` or `exit 0` at the end of your script.

---

<sup>¹ at least for the *body* part. For `for i in $(exit 42); do :; done`, most shells return 0 (AT&T ksh being the exception). They all return 0 for `for i in; do :; done < "$(echo /dev/null; exit 42)"`.</sup>

Comment: Regarding the paragraph about ignoring errors: Using `exit` will be more efficient than `true`, since `exit` is builtin to the shell, but `true` will need to spawn a process. Even quicker would be a simple no-op (`:`) !

Comment: @user1404316, `true` is a built-in in all modern Bourne-like shells including `bash`, just like `:` and `exit` (well those are _special_ builtins, but that makes no difference in that regard). And `true` and `false` **are** the commands to express boolean values there.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas : I just now double-checked and get conflicting indications in bash version 4.4.12. `man builtins` does **not** include `true` in the synopsis at the beginning of the page, or anywhere else. OTOH, `type true` does indicate that it is a shell builtin. Maybe a documentation bug. `man bash` also does **not** document `true`.

Comment: @user1404316, true/false builtins were added in bash-2.0 (96) and zsh-2.0 (91). ksh always had them, though initially (including in ksh86) true was defined as a builtin alias for ":" and false for "let 0". ash originally had true but not false (added later in the 90s on the various BSDs).